# Is there any way to calculate DRAM access latency (cycles) from data size?

Tags: memory, latency

I need to calculate DRAM access latency using given data size to be transfered between DRAM-SRAM

The data is seperated to "load size" and "store size" and "number of iteration of load and store" is given. 
I think the features I need to consider are many like first DRAM access latency, transfer one word latency, address load latency etc..
Is there some popular equation to get this by given information?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make a simulation based on the exact details of your system? I don't think there is a one-size-fits-all-possible-systems answer.

Comment: @jakub_d I agree, and I don't want the exactly correct value. I just want to roughly estimate the latency. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your question has many parts, I think I can help better if I knew the ultimate goal? If it's simply to measure access latency:

If you are using an x86 processor maybe the [Intel Memory Latency Checker](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intelr-memory-latency-checker) will help

> Intel® Memory Latency Checker (Intel® MLC) is a tool used to measure memory latencies and b/w, and how they change with increasing load on the system. It also provides several options for more fine-grained investigation where b/w and latencies from a specific set of cores to caches or memory can be measured as well.

If not x86, I think the Gem5 Simulator has what you are looking for, here is the [main page](http://gem5.org/Main_Page) but more specifically, for your needs, I think this [config for Gem5](http://learning.gem5.org/book/part1/cache_config.html) will be the most helpful.

Now regarding a popular equation, the best I could find is this Carnegie Melon paper that goes over my head: https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~omutlu/pub/chargecache_low-latency-dram_hpca16.pdf However, it looks like your main "features" as you put it revolve around cores and memory channels. The equation from the paper:

`Storagebits = C ∗MC ∗Entries∗(EntrySizebits +LRUbits)`

Is used to create a cache that will ultimately (the goal of ChargeCache) reduce access latency in DRAM. I'm sure this isn't the equation you are looking for but just a piece of the puzzle. The `LRUbits` relate to the cache this mechanism (in the memory controller, no DRAM modification necessary) creates.

`EntrySizebits` is determined by this equation `EntrySizebits = log2(R)+log2(B)+log2(Ro)+1`  and

> R, B, and Ro are the number of ranks, banks, and rows in DRAM, respectively

I was surprised to learn highly charged rows (recently accessed) will have a significantly lower access latency.

If this goes over your head as well, maybe this 2007 paper by Ulrich Drepper titled [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf) will help you find the elements you need for your equation. I'm still working through this paper myself, and there is some dated references but those depend on what cpu you're working with. Hope this helps, I look forward to being corrected on any of this, as I'm new to the topic.